# (K)ubuntu 19.10 can't print text files from console

Tags: command-line, printing, text, stdout

I have trouble with printing system on my Kubuntu 19.10

I tried so many things that i can't track completely, but the following is the core of the problem.

```
$ echo "test" | lp -d Boomaga
request id is Boomaga-339 (0 file(s))
$ echo "test" | lp
request id is HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP-340 (0 file(s))
```

The same with lpr

[kubuntu printer queues display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibYyd.png)

Every attempt to do this ends with "Filter failed" message

I don't know which filter, so what to install, reinstall, remove or delete directly.

Fortunately printing from graphical applications such as firefox, okular, libre office works ok.

I thing the problem is in the way that normaly converts text files to postscript, but I'm not sure.

Some time ago, i was trying so hard to solve this, that i have randomly installed "lpr - BSD lpr/lpd line printer spooling system" which breaks also printing from all KDE based applications and it took me several weeks to find out.
Now i can print from the applications directly throwing out postscript output (if i understand it correctly) but i need from time to time print the text files, or text from stdout.

The cups log didn't gave me any useful information even debug was enabled.

Any hint what to check or what to reinstall is really welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at `lpstat -t`?, pointed a browser to `http://localhost:631`?, done `service cups status`?, looked at `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/cupsd`?

Comment: $ LANG="" lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP
device for Boomaga: boomaga:/
device for HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP?serial=000000000QH997EDSI1c
Boomaga accepting requests since Sun Mar  1 01:42:37 2020
HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP accepting requests since Sun Mar  1 01:43:26 2020
printer Boomaga is idle.  enabled since Sun Mar  1 01:42:37 2020
printer HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP is idle.  enabled since Sun Mar  1 01:43:26 2020

Comment: $ LANG="" sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/cupsd
[sudo] password for ladmanj: 
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-03-15 19:34:28 CET, end at Sun 2020-03-15 21:47:43 CET. --
-- No entries --

Comment: $ LANG="" service cups status
* cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-03-15 00:00:23 CET; 21h ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
 Main PID: 2818 (cupsd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 12.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           |-2818 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
           `-2837 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://

Mar 15 00:00:23 thinkpad systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.

Comment: I don't see anything weird in the messages I posted above, also http://localhost:631 doesn't display anything exceptional.

Comment: Don't add data in comments. Rather edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1217172/edit ) your post, and add info there, with proper formatting. WIthout the formatting, it's too hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a solution:

1st
Sun 28 Jun 2020 02:45:17 PM EDT <------------------/ trying cups install /---
open CUPS 2.3.1
http://localhost:631/

After install only prints the first line of text file, and acts like the job is done?

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 63080 Apr 10 09:12 /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf <--------/  likely problem  /---
D [28/Jun/2020:14:46:02 -0400] [Job 59] PID 71266 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf) crashed on signal 6.

[ jack @ s0n5-u20 scr-2  ~ ]
$ echo "a" | CHARSET=utf-8 /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf 1 user title 1 "PageSize=A4" > out.pdf
Unsupported OTF font / glyf table 
texttopdf: fontembed/sfnt.c:651: otf_get_width: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Print text files works on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
gvim
konsole prt sc
$ enscript /tmp/le0203 
    [ 1 page * 1 copy ] sent to printer ----/   works  /---
    but has file location on header ???  not desireable.
$ enscript -B /tmp/le0203
    no file location header !
```

print text files fails
lp
lpr

Using enscript -B is a workaround, <------/ my tmp solution /--

It's weird that Ubuntu 20.04 is not tested for lp and lpr use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm returning here after a time.
My problem was solved many months ago, but I forgot to provide feedback here.

The expected functionality was disabled by erroneous installation of package:

```
lpr - BSD lpr/lpd line printer spooling system
```

It started to work after its removal, and installation of:

```
cups-bsd - Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - BSD commands
```

I hope that it may help somebody with similar problem.